# pre-loading custom functions when running sheets daily script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using the 'Cryptofinance' custom function in Google spreadsheets. I have written a custom script which runs daily using the trigger functionality of the app scripts.

```js
function daily() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Liquidity");
  var value = sh.getRange("B36").getValue();
  var lastRow = whichRow();
  lastRow += 1;
  ss.getSheetByName("Liquidity over time").getRange("B" + lastRow).setValue(value);
  ss.getSheetByName("Liquidity over time").getRange("A" + lastRow).setValue(new Date());
}

function whichRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Avals = ss.getSheetByName("Liquidity over time").getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length; 
  return Alast;
}
```

Basically it should pick up the value from a field and add a row so I can run a chart on this column.

The output when I run it manually from the script editor can look like this;

```
1337999,52
```

The output when it gets run by the daily function looks like this:

```
#NAME?
```

It didn't help with the .flush() function and I haven't been able to understand the sheets lifecycle in combination with the custom function.

How can I make sure the sheet is pre-loaded before the script runs?

Comment: You code worked fine for me. Perhaps try it out on a brand new sheet. It might be the cell formatting that causes the error.

Comment: It works fine for me as well when I run it manually. It's when it gets run by the daily trigger that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the Spreadsheet and then set it as active:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234567890");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
```

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setActiveSpreadsheet(Spreadsheet)

Comment: This was the right answer and code to go with it. The below answer was also very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

On time-driven triggers avoid the use of call functions, even custom functions, that use getActiveSpreadsheet and other "get active" methods. Instead use openById or other similar methods.

## Explanation

SpreadsheetApp.flush() ensures the pending changes made to the script are applied, so it doesn't make sense to put it as the first action of a function.

On the other hand, on Google Apps Script, the user that has opened the spreadsheet establish which spreadsheet is active, on time-driven triggers getActiveSpreadsheet returns null, in other words, we could say that "active" means "being used at this time by an user".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll be testing with openById, let's see if it resolves the issue.